# Standard Input Iterator Issues

Tags: c++, stl

This is my code for solving one of the hackerrank question. In short, i am reading input for each test, solving and outputing it. For some reason, it is not reading the value of m correctly in the second iteration of the for loop based on t

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool debug = true;

    istream_iterator<int> iit(cin);
    int tests = *(iit++);

    for (int t = 0; t < tests; t++) {
        int m = *(iit++);
        int n = *(iit++);

        vector<int> ele; ele.reserve(n);
        copy_n(iit, n, back_inserter(ele));

        if (debug) {
            cout << "M: " << m << ", N: " << n << ", Elements: ";
            copy(ele.begin(), ele.end(), ostream_iterator<int> (cout, " "));
            cout << endl;
        }


        unordered_map<int, int> map;
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            map[ele[index]] = index;
        }

        bool found = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            auto robber = m - ele[index];
            auto search_iterator = map.find(robber);
            if (search_iterator != map.end()) {
                int I = index + 1;
                int J = search_iterator->second + 1;
                cout << I << " " << J << endl;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (debug && !found) {
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the input and output

```
04:47:20 vagrant@vm ~/cpp/icecream_parlor $ cat input.txt
2
4
5
1 4 5 3 2
4
4
2 2 4 3
04:52:49 vagrant@vm ~/cpp/icecream_parlor $ g++-4.9 -std=c++14 main.cpp -o app && ./app < input.txt
M: 4, N: 5, Elements: 1 4 5 3 2
1 4
M: 1, N: 4, Elements: 4 2 2 4
Not found
04:52:51 vagrant@vm ~/cpp/icecream_parlor $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike normal iterators, stream iterators behave slightly differently. 
A stream iterator is bound to some I/O stream and a copy of the iterator is still bound to the same stream.

So it violates pure value semantics, similar to how a smart pointer works, but that violation is not very obvious since it has an iterator interface.

When you call `copy_n`, you passed the iterator `iit`  by value, and when the function exits, `iit` has not changed its internal bookkeeping state, but the underlying stream `cin` has got mutated because when `copy_n` incremented its copy of the iterator, the stream seeked forward internally.

This gotcha is a consequence of violating the contract that iterators do not change the container they point to when you read from them or increment them.

I've used stream iterators many times, I never came across this quirk, because I've never reused a stream iterator after calling `copy()` on it.

I think one has to just remember that this can happen and try never to reuse stream iterators after passing them to a library function.

I cannot think of a way to solve this in the language without breaking existing code that works with stream iterators.